# Creating holes in the assembly in Solidworks

Tags: solidworks

I have 2 parts in an assembly that I am trying to connect using 2 bolts. I want to create the holes by creating 2 circles on a surface and by cutting through both objects using the circles. If I do this using the Extruded Cut option in the Assembly Features, I am able to create the holes in the assembly but the original objects don't get updated with the holes, so I cannot export them as STLs (they only exist in the assembly). If I try to create the holes with the Edit Components option, I can edit one of the objects, but it doesn't affect the second object at all (the hole only goes through the first object and disapperas on the second object). I am confused. I need to do that change on the assembly, because it is difficult to align the holes if I edit the parts separately. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make the hole on one part, in the part environment. Then use edit part inside the assembly to edit the second part - you can then line up the hole easily. It doesn't need to be in one cut feature

Comment: I agree with Jonathan.  Assembly usage is essential for multipart assemblies.  Use Hole Wizard for making holes.